# Blocking a web directory with AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-application-load-balancer

I have servers behind a AWS ALB that have a dir that I would like to protect. e.g `/api`

I would like the `/api` dir available to certain IPs and blocked to the rest of the word

I have no problem blocking the dir by causing requests to respond with a 404. However when I setup a rule to redirect requests from a valid IP and dirname ( 194.90.1.5 && /apidocs )
when it redirects to `/api` I get the 404 triggered by the other rule.

I have tried switching  the order of the rules but that did not help.

Can this be done with AWS ALB and am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What rules and how exactly did you set them up?

Comment: rule 1 says IF ip = 194.90.1.5 AND request is to /apidocs THEN fwd to /api dir

rule 2 says IF any request to /api should get a 404

so it seems rule 1 instead of bypassing rule 2 actually triggers rule 2.

I tried switching the order and putting rule 2 first with no luck  - thanks !!